# F# - Insert element in sorted list (tail-recursive)

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am trying to convert the following normal-recursive code to tail-recursive in F#, but I am failing miserably.

```
let rec insert elem lst = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> [elem]
    | hd::tl -> if hd > elem then 
                    elem::lst
                else 
                    hd::(insert elem tl) 

let lst1 = []

let lst2 = [1;2;3;5]

printfn "\nInserting 4 in an empty list:  %A" (insert 4 lst1)
printfn "\nInserting 4 in a sorted list:  %A" (insert 4 lst2)
```

Can you guys help? Unfortunately I am a beginner in f#. Also, can anyone point me to a good tutorial to understand tail-recursion?

Answer (score 2):

The point of tail recursion is the following: the last operation before returning from a function is a call to itself; this is called a *tail call*, and is where *tail recursion* gets its name from (the recursive call is in last, i.e. tail position).

Your function is not tail recursive because at least one of its branches has an operation after the recursive call (the list cons operator).

The usual way of converting a recursive function into a tail-recursive function is to add an argument to accumulate intermediate results (the *accumulator*). When it comes to lists, and when you realize that the only elementary list operation is prepending an element, this also means that after you are through with processing your list, it will be reversed, and thus the resulting accumulator will usually have to be reversed again.

With all these points in mind, and given that we do not want to change the function's public interface by adding a parameter that is superfluous from the caller's point of view, we move the real work to an internal subfunction. This particular function is slightly more complicated because after the element has been inserted, there is nothing else to do but concatenate the two partial lists again, one of which is now in reverse order while the other is not. We create a second internal function to handle that part, and so the whole function looks as follows:

```
let insert elm lst =
    let rec iter acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev (elm :: acc)
        | (h :: t) as ls ->
            if h > elm then finish (elm :: ls) acc
            else iter (h :: acc) t
    and finish acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | h :: t -> finish (h :: acc) t
    iter [] lst
```

For further studying, Scott Wlaschin's *F# for Fun and Profit* is a great resource, and tail recursion is handled in a larger chapter about recursive types and more: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds

Comment: It did worked just fine...but I will like to skip the ***finish*** altogether.

Comment: let rec finish acc = function
| [] -> acc
| hd::tail -> finish (hd::acc) tail

let insert elem lst =
    let rec helper acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev (elem::acc)
        | hd::tail ->
            if hd > elem then finish (elem::hd::tail) acc
                else helper (hd::acc) tail
    helper [] lst